# JavaScript: Why won't my form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

My problem is that my form, `<form name="enrollment" method="post" action="submit.php">` will not submit. My submit button looks like: `<input class="buttons" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="Submit" />`.

It calls this JavaScript function:

```
// Returns true if there are no errors and false if there are errors
function validate() {
  // Something is not returning true here so that the form is not being submitted
  if ( !window.err_exist ) {
    // No errors
    return true;
  }
  // There are errors
  alert("Errors exist in the form!");
  return false;
}
```

The variable `window.err_exist` is defined in the function `getReviewValues()`. In `getReviewValues()`, I set `window.err_exist = false;`. Then, I validate the form with conditionals of the form:

```
// Name
var r_string = "Name: ";

if ( document.forms["enrollment"]["name"].value.trim() == "" ) {
    r_string += "<span class=\"error\">This is a required field!</span>";
    window.err_exist = true;
} else {
    r_string += document.forms["enrollment"]["name"].value;
}
```

Then, at the end of `getReviewValues()`, I `return r_string;` for dynamic feedback on the status of the form validations. That is, messages like `"Name: This is a required field!"`.

Now, if I fill out my form but leave some things blank so that I have validation errors, I get the alert `"Errors exist in the form!"` and the form doesn't submit. Great! However, when I fill out my form so that I have no validation errors, I do **not** get the error message. Great! But, oh no! The form still doesn't submit. And it should!

So, since I'm not getting the error message, then the execution path must be in the conditional `if ( !window.err_exist )`. I can see this because function then returns `true` so that the function never gets to send out the message. But, if it returns `true`, then my form should submit. So it must be returning `false`, since the form is not submitting. But if it's returning `false`, then the execution path cannot be in the assumed conditional. If that were the case, then I would get the message but I do not get the message. This is a contradiction.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but note that if a form has an element with `name="submit"`, then theform.submit points to that element instead of the form's submit method.  I would avoid setting the name attribute of any form element to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an "onclick" handler on your submit button, use the "onsubmit" event on your form element.  For example:

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()">
```

At this point, as long as your validate method is returning true or false correctly... it should behave how you expect.

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onsubmit.asp for a better reference.

Comment: When I make those changes and then submit my form with errors present, it will give me my error message and then the form will successfully submit.

Comment: This means there are bugs in your validate function. The easiest way to debug this is to set a breakpoint (see: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-dynamic-javascript) at the top of your validate method. Step through and determine where it's returning. While you're doing this, you can print the current values of variables in the console. This will give you a HUGE clue if window.err_exist is not what you expect it to be. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

When you validation is a success (window.err_exist != false) the script returns true. Thus you are returning true for a click event not a submit.

This could be fixed by doing what jeltine says `<form onsubmit="validate()">` or it could be fixed by replacing the

```
<input class="buttons" type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return validate()" value="Submit" />
```

with

```
<input class="buttons" type="button" name="submit" onclick="validate()" value="Submit" />
```

Then changing the validate function to call `form.submit();` on no errors.

EXAMPLE:

```
   //must add id to get element by id
    <form name="enrollment" id="enrollment" method="post" action="submit.php">

function validate() {
  // Something is not returning true here so that the form is not being submitted
  if ( !window.err_exist ) {
    // call submit on form
    var myform = document.getElementById("enrollment");
    myform.submit();
  }
  // There are errors
  alert("Errors exist in the form!");
  return false;
}
```

The advantage to doing it this way is that you have more control over changing form parameters such as action or method if needed. If these will not be needed then just change to `onsubmit=""`.

Comment: When I make those changes and then submit my form with errors present, it will give me my error message and then the form will successfully submit. Why would it have this kind of behavior?

Comment: Try explicitly setting window.err_exist = false;